# ¿Para qué sirve el método getWeightToEnd() en algoritmos de grafos en Java?

Tags: java, algoritmos

como dice el título de mi pregunta, me gustaría saber para qué sirve el método getWeightToEnd() en Java. Tengo que programar este método de un grafo, pero no termino de entender cuál es su función. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: getWeightToEnd() te permite calcular el peso que existe desde un nodo hasta otro ingresando como parámetros estos dos valores.

Comment: @EfrenNarvaez deberias publicar tu comentario como respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getWeightToEnd() te permite calcular el peso que existe desde un nodo hasta otro ingresando como parámetros estos dos valores.